# How to detect if caps lock is already active?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

Supposing I want to detect if the caps lock is active so if the keys are upper case, what can I use in c++ with windows?

I would need an equivalent of `Console.CapsLock` in C#

I already tried using `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CAPITAL)` but I don't need the key state I need to know the "toggle" status

Comment: I don't get how [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905342/winapi-how-to-get-the-caps-lock-state) doesn't answer your question. Please define the difference between the "key state" and "toggle status" in your own words.

Comment: @CoryKramer It doesn't tell me if it is active, it tells me when it is actually pressed

Comment: [GetKeyState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301(VS.85).aspx) and `GetAsyncKeyState()` will return the toggle state of the key as well if it is up or down.  It is stored in the least significant bit of the return.

Comment: Console.CapsLock itself just calls GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL)

Comment: Why are you adding `C#`? the OP is referring to a call from C# but the question is not about C#, it's about C++.

Answer (score 6):

The value from [GeyKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx) (Win32) has a low order bit which gives its current toggle status.

Comment: `(GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) != 0` actually this worked thanks everyone